# I cannot load my projects from iPython in a conda terminal window on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda

I have a reading and writing disability, so apologies if something sounds less clear.

Primarily I develop on Windows and have since 1991. The last ten years I have developed in Python on Windows. Now, I am trying to migrate to Mac OS Silicon based machines for what I see as obvious hardware improvement and I am running into difficulties.

When I start a terminal window, from the Mac search Terminal.app I am presented with a window that has already started in my conda base env.
I then, without issue, am able to start iPython by typing ipython at the command prompt.

Once in iPython, there in my troubles begin.

```
    Python 3.10.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Nov 22 2022, 08:25:13) [Clang 14.0.6 ]
    Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
    IPython 8.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

    In [1]: import pyrv

    ModuleNotFoundError                       
    Traceback (most recent call last)
    Cell In[1], line 1
    ----> 1 import pyrv
```

If I navigate to the location of the pyrv project file it begins to load but fails as it tries to import another project of mine, config, located in another location and says it cannot find module.

```
    In [6]: import pyrv
    
    ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
    Cell In[6], line 1
    ----> 1 import pyrv

    File ~/projects/rellue/pyrv/pyrv/__init__.py:7
          4 # Standard Library
          5 import os
    ----> 7 from config import Configurations
          9 # PyRV
         10 from pyrv.ai import Features

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

If I navigate to the config location, I can import it just fine.

```
    In [13]: import config

    In [14]:
```

If I then navigate back to the pyrv project, now that config has been loaded, I can load pyrv.

There has to be a better way.

I read that I should change my .zshrc file, the contents are below, but I seem no closer to being able to start iPython and just loading pyrv.

```
    export PATH=$PATH:/Users/davidrpalmer/projects/rellue/pyrv/pyrv
    export PATH=$PATH:/Users/davidrpalmer/projects/rellue/config/config

    # >>> conda initialize >>>
    # !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
    __conda_setup="$('/Users/davidpalmer/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        eval "$__conda_setup"
    else
        if [ -f "/Users/davidpalmer/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
            . "/Users/davidpalmer/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        else
            export PATH="/Users/davidpalmer/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
        fi
    fi
    unset __conda_setup
    # <<< conda initialize <<<
```

This did not seem to change anything. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Please fix your formatting